# Seized resource physical location

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I would like to find the location of the seized resource whenever a resource is seized. For instance in the job shop example model- see the attached photo, the material is moved by a forklift from a rack to a table in order to be process by a CNC machine. There are 3 CNC machines and each has its own table that serves as a queue. Now when a table is seized, can I know the coordinate points of that table before the material is moved to it?

[image: The job shop layout photo]

The reason I'm asking because I have a similar model with more tables and machine, and speed in which the forklifts travel depends on the distance between the rack and the table. I have a discrete speed function for different distances. I want to get the location of the seized table in order to find the distance between the current location of the material and the seized table so I can choose the speed for the forklift in the following moveTo entity.

Answer (score 1):

For the job show model, if you want to know the location of the CNC when it's seized, you can do that in the on seize unit action of the seize block by getting the x and y coordinates:

```
unit.getX();
unit.getY();
unit.getZ();
```